# Pandas Timedelta attributes (_m, _s): odd behaviour

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, timedelta

I have witnessed some strange behaviour **accessing attributes** such as `_m` or `_s` from a **pandas timedelta object** .
Let me explain the problem with a minimal example, that I run from the console in PyCharm (PyCharm 2020.2.3 (Community Edition))

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
```

```py
>>> #  Creating a dataFrame with 2 pandas timedeltas:
... df_test=pd.DataFrame({"Timedeltas":[pd.Timedelta('1 days 1:01:01'), pd.Timedelta('2 days 2:02:02')]})
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:56.230217907')
```

```py
>>> mean_timedelta=df_test['Timedeltas'].mean()
... print(mean_timedelta._m)
0
```

```py
>>> mean_timedelta=df_test['Timedeltas'].mean()
... print(mean_timedelta)
... print(mean_timedelta._m)
1 days 13:31:31.500000
31
```

- Why isn't *31* printed the first time I executed `print(mean_timedelta._m)`? And why do I get *`0`* instead?
- Why is *31* printed only if I run `print(mean_timedelta)` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mean_timedelta` is an object of type `Timedelta`. The attributes of the objects are not populated when the object is created by assignment. You can check it by accessing the attribute `_is_populated`.

When you first print the whole object with `print(mean_timedelta)`, the attributes are internally populated. It is the reason why you can then access the attributes such as `_m`:

```
mean_timedelta=df_test['Timedeltas'].mean()
print(mean_timedelta.is_populated)
print(mean_timedelta)
print(mean_timedelta.is_populated)
print(mean_timedelta._m)
print(mean_timedelta.is_populated)
```

Output:

```
False
1 days 13:31:31.500000
True
31
True
```

My answer is based on the [source code of the class](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timedeltas.pyx#L701).

To intentionaly populate it you can call:

```
mean_timedelta._ensure_components()
```

In case you need to get the minutes in another way, you can do:

```
print((mean_timedelta.seconds//60)%60)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer is very clear. I still wonder why it returns *0* if it is *not populated*: for me it is like returning something which isn't "true". The next question I would have is: can I actually somehow intentionally populate it? What would be the best way? Because printing it is ok, but not, shall I say, very pro.

Comment: I don't know neither why it returns 0. Maybe because the attributes are initialized this way. It would be necessary to more investigate the code.  To intentionally populate it you can call `mean_timedelta._ensure_components()`.